# Changed my bundle ID to add push notifications, now it comes up with error: Bundle identity differs from prior bundle identifier

Tags: ios, xcode, push-notification, app-store-connect, app-id

I made an app which had a bundle id: `rexrapps.ksisounds`. I then needed push notifications so I changed it to `com.rexrapps.ksisounds`. The push works fine. But when I try to submit, as you may suspect it says: *the bundle identifier differs from prior bundle identifier*.

I have worked tirelessly to try and fix this to no avail.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: If I remember it correctly, what I did was logging into developer site, select modify and/or request to regenerate the distribution certification.  And use it to sign and rebuild your app.

Comment: @user523234 I don't think this works as i can already build and run it I cant verify the archive and submit it to the app store, and there is nothing wrong with the certificates.

Comment: Just read your description again... You need to update your bundle ID in the iTunes Connect.

Comment: @user523234 how can I do that?